# map reduce showing different output from find query

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

i have two queries running on same collection , one using find , other using map reduce, both giving different result.

Map reduce

```
  db.customerTrend.mapReduce(function() {
    emit(this.value.trendDate, {
        count: 1
    })
}, function(key, values) {
    var sum = 0;
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        sum = sum + 1;
    });
    return {
        sum: sum
    }
}, {
    out: "totalByTrendDate"
})
```

it outputs

```
{ "_id" : null, "value" : { "sum" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-12-18T18:30:00Z"), "value" : { "sum" : 26 } }
```

Find query

```
db.customerTrend.find({
    "value.trendDate": ISODate("2015-12-18T18:30:00Z")
}).count()
```

outputs

```
30105
```

so for same date find query shows 30105 records, while map reduce query shows only 26, though the correct one is find query.